# C11: how to quickly convert a char array into ints, then modify ints and update char array

Tags: c, performance, type-conversion, c11

There are two parts of the problem that I don't know how to solve:

#### Input

The user can enter some inputs like `12,14y` or `15m` and I need to extract the two ints and the character. For now, I simply use:

```
char buffer[50];
scanf("%s", buffer);

switch (buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]) {
   // ... I use this to read the last char
}
```

This can give me the information of how many ints I have to read:

- one in the `m,n` case -> `sscanf(buffer, "%d%c", int1, c)`
- two in the `y,s,b` case -> `sscanf(buffer, "%d,%d%c", int1, int2, c)`

I need these numbers for the core of my program, so I need int values not only the string.
The problem is that online I read about `sscanf` inefficiency and I need a good way to do this task quickly.

#### Output

My code has to modify these numbers just in one case (y) and conserve a modified copy of the user input. For example, users input is `1,12y` then I have to modify it in `1,10y` and store it as a char array so it's not only an input. The modification of int2 it's quite long to explain, I can say that the new value would be less than the original one (in my example from 12 I get 10). The only idea I have about this it's how to create the new char array: I can calculate int1 and int2 length trying to divide them with increasing power of 10 until I get a result between 1 and 9. e.g.:

```
int1 = 201:
       201  no
       20.1 no
       2.01 yes
=> 3 tries, length = 3
```

Then I use a malloc. But then, how can I write my "output" in the new char array? e.g.:

```
input = "1,201y"
  -> int1 = 1,         int2 = 201
  -> lenght(int1) = 1, length(int2) = 2

// if the core program sets int2 = 51, then
char *out = malloc(1+2+1):
// now I have to write "1,51y" in this char array
```

I've coded the "core" program already, but now I'd want to improve a fast "translation" of user input (because in the core program I need to know if it's a int1m or int1n or int1,int2y or int1,int2s or int1,int2b command) and I don't know how to modify user input to save it in a string (for strings I use char arrays dynamically allocated). Only the y command could modify int2.

I hope that it's clear what I've to done.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What are expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: When you say character do you mean character array? As in int to string?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, maybe you're looking for `sprintf`?

Comment: This is the counterpart of your other question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586535/fast-char-to-int-and-fast-read-of-last-letter-in-c11 ) isn't it? I.e. the output of what you want to do here is the input to that question? In that question it turned out that reading the documentation of scanf() was very enlightening. Did you read the docs on printf and sprintf()?

Comment: Also, you have still the same problem, of declining to rovide a [mre] of what you have, because your professor does not allow, haven't you?

Comment: Did you consider redesigning the format of your data files? If you output here a format which is there easy to read AND here easy to print, then your problem would become much simpler.

Comment: By the way, people here are usually in a better and more helpful mood when they see that questions are asked after taking the [tour] (which you did not) and ideally reading [ask].

Comment: I've tried to explain in the best way my question

Comment: Without sample code (e.g your current one) it is quite difficult to understand your problem. Currently you show only `scanf` calls, which give a little help in understanding.

Comment: `I read about sscanf inefficiency` that's just strange. People use shell language, python, java with _a lot_ more overhead then what `sscanf` call does. The question is very broad. Do you ask how to read input faster then `scanf`, or how to store characters in a buffer or how to modify the user input? I believe you should rather read a good C book rather then asking vague stackoverflow questions about basic C operations.

Comment: Also, remember about [rules of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub). There is no point in "doing it faster then sscanf" if `sscanf` is not bottleneck of your program. First profile the program, then use the profiling information to optimize the slowest paths.

Comment: Are you sure that after you parsed your text and [optionally] updated some values you need to build another text out of it? Why? So that you would have to parse it later again? Couldn't you just pass that data structure around?

Comment: @KamilCuk It depends on context. On a low end embedded system, `sscanf` & friends are regarded as horribly inefficient... If you program some MCU with lets say 16k flash 4k RAM, then there is no way you can justify blowing up 2-3k flash and half the RAM just to use `sscanf`. You'd be dismissed as a "PC programmer" (not a good thing). This is where the competent programmer either investigates using `strtol` or roll out their own version.

Comment: However, scanf and malloc are equally unlikely to appear in such embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that online I read about sscanf inefficiency

"Online" isn't a very trustworthy source. Inefficiency depends entirely on what you compare the function with.

If you compare with any plain C function then *all* of the `stdio.h` functions are very much inefficient. As is `malloc` for that matter. However, printing to the screen and waiting on the human user are by far the largest bottlenecks in this program, so you might want to re-consider why and what you are optimizing.

That being said, you can easily roll out a manual specialized version of the string to integer conversion, by calling strtol family of functions. Here's a version supporting exactly 1 or 2 integers in the input string (it can easily be rewritten to use a loop instead):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int parse_input (const char* input, int* i1, int* i2, char* ch)
{
  char* endptr=NULL;
  const char* cptr=input;
  int result;
  
  result = strtol(cptr, &endptr, 10);
  if(cptr==endptr) 
  {
    return 0; 
  }
  *i1 = result;
  
  if(*endptr != ',')
  {
    *ch = *endptr;
    return 1;
  }
  
  cptr=endptr+1;
  result = strtol(cptr, &endptr, 10);
  if(cptr==endptr)
  {
    return 0; 
  }
 
  *i2 = result;
  *ch = *endptr;
  return 2;
}
```

Some extra error handling might be needed too. This gives around 50 instructions when compiled for x86_64, not counting `strtol` calls. Where some 20 of those instructions are related to the parameter stacking and calling convention.